# How to show that..., $A(C_1)=\{z:|z-1|\leq 1, \theta \in [\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}] \}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $C_1=\{z:|z|\leq 1, \theta \in [\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}] \}$ and $A(z)=z-1$. Define $A(C_1)$. How to show that $A(C_1)\neq\{z:|z-1|\leq 1, \arg(z)=\theta \in [\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}] \}$, but $A(C_1)=\{z:|z-1|\leq 1, \arg(z)=\theta \in [\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}] \}$?

My solution for $A(C_1)$:

$A(z)$ is translation, so called elementary function, which translates set $C_1$ one unit to the negative direction of real axis. Thus  $A(C_1)=\{z:|z-1|\leq 1, \theta \in [\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}] \}$. Comments on my solution? I'm not sure whether my solution is appropriate proof.

Comment: @DimitriosNtalampekos: Can you tell me why $A(z)=z-1$ translates to right side of real axis? It should translate -1 to the left side of real axis regardless of the the domain/area.

Comment: Sorry I had something else in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $A$ is a translation, hence it takes any subset of $\mathbb C$ and it moves it in certain direction; in our case it moves our subset (that is the left half of the closed unit circle) horizontally, shifting it backward of exactly one unit. No more: in particular $A$ is not a rotation, hence the left half of the closed unit circle will remain the *left* half of a unit circle (but not centered in the origin!), so you won't change the argument of the complex number of the image (under $A$) of your subset: this is why $A(C_1)\neq$ the first set you wrote (because of the argument conditions).

But pay attention! $|z-1|\le1$ denotes the point of the complex plane whose distance from $z_0=1$ is less or equal than $r=1$; so you would have translated your circle forward, not backward! But the translation takes the points backward, so you must consider the point whose distance from $z_0=-1$ is less or equal than $r=1$, i.e. $|z-(-1)|\le1$. Finally you have
$$
A(C_1)=\{z\in\mathbb C\;:|z+1|\le1,\;\theta=\arg z\in[\pi/2,3\pi/2]\}\;.
$$

Comment: @Joe.. Thanks. Do you agree that $z(\theta)=e^{i\theta}-1, \arg{z}\in[\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}]$ is function for left half of the unit circle around $A(C_1)$? if yes, how do you get that from $A(C_1)$?

Comment: Yes, if by "around $A(C_1)$" you mean "the boundary, but not the vertical part": the function $z(\theta)=e^{i\theta}-1$ parametrizes the circular part of $\partial A(C_1)$. But this function doesen't describe the whole $A(C_1)$. Such a function is $z(\theta,r):=re^{i\theta}-1$ for $\theta\in[\pi/2,3\pi/2]\,,r\in[0,1]$. Finally, I got these functions simply arguing on the objects I treat with: it's faster, smarter and simpler than an analytical argument that yelds you from $A(C_1)$ to $z(\theta)$.

Comment: I mean: I need to describe all complex numbers such that etc etc: they are simply the ones described by $e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta\in[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ but traslated backward of one unit: hence $z(\theta)=e^{i\theta}-1$ works as I want and I'm ok.
I know that an analytical argument, made all by formulas can appear safer, harmless, but IMHO it's important to arguing also in a different way, sometimes! :-)

Comment: @Joe.. I just ask one more thing; how to show that if $B(z)=2z$, then $B(C_2)=\{z: |z+1/2|\leq 1, \arg{z}\in[\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}] \}$, where $C_2=\{z:|z-(-1/2)|\leq 1/2, \arg{z}\in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}] \}$?

Comment: $B$ is an expansion of ratio $2$ and $C_2$ is the left half of the closed circle, centered in $-1/2$ of radius $1/2$. Hence applying $B$ on $C_2$ you simply expand it. You don't move it, nor rotate it. Hence $B(C_2)$ is again a left ($B$ isn't a rotation) half of a closed circle centered in $-1/2$ ($B$ isn't a translation): the only thing that changes is the radius that now is twice as before hence is $2\cdot\frac12=1$. So you have exactly the set you wrote.

Comment: @laovultai: let me ask you a thing. Why the $+50$ bounty went to another user if you choose my answer, as the correct one? I can't understand this

Comment: @Joe.. I really try to make a direct answer to a direct question: I didn't make this on purpose, but he had less reputation credits and answer was not wrong if he uses another parametrization. I guess I'm making a mistake and I say thanks for letting me know this fault.

Answer (score 1):

If $C_1$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\theta$ is the argument, then $C_1$ is simply the halfball $$\{x+iy\,|\,x\leq 0,x^2+y^2\leq 1\}.$$ If you move everything one unit to the left, you get a halfball $$\{x+iy\,|\,x\leq -1,(x-(-1))^2+y^2\leq 1\}.$$ The argument ranges from $3\pi/4$ (corresponding to $-1+i$) to $5\pi/4$ (corresponding to $-1-i$), so none of the two answers is correct and $A(C_1)$ is, in fact, $\{|z-(-1)|\leq 1,\, \mathrm{arg} \,z\in[3\pi/4, 5\pi/4]\}$.

Comment: @PeterFranek.. Because the circle around $A(C_1)$ is $z(\theta)=e^{i\theta}-1$, you get that $\theta \in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}]$. If you had another parametrization for $z(\theta)$, then I might tend to $\theta \in [\frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}]$. Am I missing something? So $A(C_1)=\{z:|z+1|\leq 1, \arg{z}\in[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]\}$.

Comment: If you parametrize $\mathbb{C}$ by $z=r\,e^{i\theta}$, then $A(C_1)$ doesn't contain any point with $\theta =\pi/2$. Such points are only on the vertical axis (purely imaginary numbers). Of course, you could parametrize $\mathbb{C}$ differently but then it's better if you write what is your $\theta$.